# TempData content is not showing in Javascript alert box

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to show the content of TempData on the click of the button. This is the button and the code:

```
<a style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" asp-action="Verify" class="Button btn btn-primary" onclick="test();">Verify Document</a>
```

This is my controller code:

```
 public  JsonResult Verify()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<b> Verification Failed </b>");
            sb.Append("<Br/>");
            sb.Append("This document is not a valid electronic reproduction of a record on file");
            sb.Append("<Br/>");
            TempData["Message"] = sb.ToString();
            return Json(new { msg = "saved" });
            
        }

<script>

   function test() {
        
        var dialog = $('#dialog').data("kendoDialog");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Verify", "Home")',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.msg == "saved") {
                    alert('@Html.Raw((string)TempData["Message"])')
                   
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

when I click the above button, I see an alert with noting displayed inside it. I tried to put the TempData like this in alert box:

```
alert('@TempData["Message"]');
```

If I put the tempData like this then I dont see the alert box at all. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the differences between client-side code and server-side code.  The JavaScript code shown is rendered *when the page first loads*.  Look at your page source in the browser and see what the `alert()` really contains.  It certainly won't contain any `TempData` values which haven't been created yet.

Then *sometime later* an AJAX request is made to the server.  And this is the server's response:

```
return Json(new { msg = "saved" });
```

And that's all the server sends to the client.  `TempData` is storing a value *server-side* that can be used when generating a view *server-side* to return to the client, but this operation isn't generating a view.  It's returning JSON.

If you want to return `Message` to the client, return it in the JSON:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<b> Verification Failed </b>");
sb.Append("<Br/>");
sb.Append("This document is not a valid electronic reproduction of a record on file");
sb.Append("<Br/>");
return Json(new { msg = "saved", message = sb.ToString() });
```

Then you can access that value in the response of the AJAX operation:

```
success: function (result) {
    if (result.msg == "saved") {
        alert(result.message);
    }
}
```

---

Further notes:

- If that click operation isn't meant to navigate to a new page, don't make it a `<a>` element.  Use a `<button>` instead.  (If it's within a `<form>` make sure to use `type="button"` if you don't want to submit the form.)
- `alert` isn't particularly robust, and you'll find that it doesn't render HTML markup/styling.  If you want to display styled output, show it on the page somewhere (even in a "modal `<div>`") instead of using `alert`.
- Naming is important.  `msg` and `message` may confuse you later.  Perhaps `msg` is more of a "status"?

Comment: @David- Thanks for the clarification. I will display the JSON in a Model